# In Inno Setup Scripting (Pascal), how do you set a global variable's initial value?

Tags: global-variables, inno-setup, default-value, pascal

(I'm pursuing Inno Setup scripting, but my understanding is that the [Code] section uses Pascal syntax, or a close approximation.  I know zero about Pascal or its standard conventions, so apologies in advance for my ignorance.)

When defining a function/procedure's local variable, syntax for defining its initial value isn't such an issue...

```
procedure MyProcedure();
var
    aFlag: Boolean;
begin
    aFlag := true;
    .
    .
    .
end;
```

But I'm hard-pressed to figure out how the initial values for global variables are handled.  For example, if I want a global Boolean variable to start out as true instead of false (the default), how would I go about accomplishing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Define them inside the code block outside of a procedure:

```
[code]
var 
  wibble: boolean;
  wobble: string;
  ...
```

and you can set their initial values in the initialize event;

```
procedure InitializeWizard(); 
begin 
    wibble := true;
    wobble := "hello";
...
```